# When I create main.go file it automatically becomes a text file

Tags: go, goland

When I create a file of any name with a `.go` prefix, GoLand's icon indicates that it is a Go file. However, when I create a `main.go` file, GoLand's icon indicates it is a plain text file. See image below. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: When I create files with any name and go prefix, they automatically become go files. When I create a main file, it automatically becomes a text and IDE sees it as text and not as the main launch file of the program.

Comment: Yes, but I think the problem is not only in the icon, yesterday when I created a main function in my project, and clicked something wrong.
All my main functions in all my projects on pc changed to the text file, and because of this a lot of errors appeared

Comment: Yea, GoLang.
I have a lot of projects on my pc that I do with ide. Now, when I open any project, the main function in it has become a text. None of the imports not work.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but after the appearance of this problem, I got many errors of the type: Build constraints exclude all Go files in '/home/bogdan/goprojects/connector/dao/mysql'

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `Preferences / Settings | Editor | File Types`, find type Text and exclude `main.go` file.